# When creating a subsite using custom template in SPO Classic Site, Does the id of html elements change?

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, site-template, classic-experience, cewp

I have a SPO Classic site. In of the forms, I have CEWP that needs to access the html elements present in the page. Now this site will be used as template. I wish to know if the code will continue to work on newly created subsites, i.e. will the id of elements remain same?

Comment: Are those HTML IDs defined by you in your custom code or are you asking about SharePoint default HTML element Ids?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Sharepoint default HTML Ids

Comment: In general, few IDs related to main HTML elements (like navigation/header/main content/command bar) will be there as is but other HTML element IDs may change. Also, it it not fixed so Microsoft can change IDs related to main HTML elements as well (any time they want in the future).

Comment: It depends on how the subsites are created. If the subsites are created as copies of the original site, then the IDs of the HTML elements should remain the same and your CEWP code should continue to work. However, if the subsites are created from scratch, then the IDs of the HTML elements may be different and you may need to modify your CEWP code to work with the new IDs. I would suggest testing your code on a newly created subsite to see if it works as expected.

Comment: @AmyJiang_MSFT Subsites will be created using site template.